# PYTHON erro index out of range

Tags: python, lista, combinações

Lá estava eu tentando criar um script que fizesse permutação, criasse uma combinação dos itens de uma lista em uma nova lista. Segue o código em python:

```
itens = []
while True:
          adition = input('Coloque os itens: ')
          if adition == 'end':
                    break
          else:
                    itens.append(adition)
                    print(adition)
comb = []

for i in itens:
           contagem = 0
           while True:
                     comb.append(i + itens[contagem])
                     print(comb)
                     if contagem == len(itens):
                               break
                     else:
                               contagem = contagem + 1
```

Mas quando eu executo o comando e ponho os itens na lista retorna o seguinte erro:

> comb.append(i+itens[contagem])
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1):

Eleve a condição `if contagem == len(itens)` para rodar antes de acessar `itens[contagem]`

```
while True:
    if contagem == len(itens):
        break
    else:
        comb.append(i + itens[contagem])
        print(comb)
        contagem = contagem + 1
```

O erro acontece no seu código porque você tenta acessar a posição `contagem` da sua lista antes de validar se ela é válida.

---

Suponha que `itens` possua os dois itens: `a` e `b`.

Na primeira iteração `cont` é igual a 0

Ele pega `a` na posição 0 e gera `aa`

Na segunda iteração `cont` é igual a 1

Ele pega `b` na posição 1 e gera `ab`

Na terceira iteração `cont` é igual a 2

Ele tenta pegar o item na posição 2, que não existe, e por isso o erro.

---

Uma forma mais simples de escrever essa lógica seria

```
while contagem < len(itens):
    comb.append(i + itens[contagem])
    print(comb)
    contagem = contagem + 1
```

Ou então utilizar outro laço `for`

```
for i in itens:
    for i2 in itens:
        comb.append(i + i2)
        print(comb)
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado! Não sabia que o while funcionava assim. Só mais uma pergunta. Por que meu código não consegue testar todas as combinações? Se uma lista tem [ 1, 2, 3, 4], o código só forma 11, 12, 13, 14 e não 11,12,13,14,21,22,23,24... e assim por diante. Por que isso acontece se eu usei o for i in lista para ler todos os itens da lista e criar uma nova combinação para cada um deles?

Comment: O código forma todas as permutações, talvez você tenha cometido outro erro na hora de corrigi-lo , veja ele funcionando [aqui](https://ideone.com/1zQ5W2)

Comment: Corrigido. No código quando eu estava corrigindo, coloquei a contagem antes do for, isso travou o laço de repetição já que contagem não resetava. Obrigado!